# Facebook's PHP SDK gives OAuth error to some users only

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've setup Facebook Connect so that users can register for my site with one click, and it works flawlessly for the majority of users, but I've gotten a few e-mails from users that get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   OAuthException: An active access token
>   must be used to query information
>   about the current user.\n  thrown in
>   /home/example/public_html/facebook.php
>   on line 453

I am unable to duplicate this error, and so I am having a hard time figuring out what is causing this.

My Facebook Connect button code:

```
<fb:login-button size="large" length="long" v="2" perms="email,user_birthday" onlogin="fb_login()"></fb:login-button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '.....', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

    function fb_login() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                window.location = 'http://example.com/register_fb.php';
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My PHP code:

```
require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '....',
  'secret' => '....',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$user = $facebook->api('/me');

//// register the user or log them in...
```

Answer (score 1):

Narrowing down what browsers they are using would help to debug this.

Absent that and based on your code, I can think of one thing that would cause this issue; the inability of the Javascript SDK to set the cookie via the login-button.

This can happen in certain browsers depending on framing, etc.

Handling this issue, you can detect if the facebook->getSession() is null and then redirect to $facebook->getLoginUrl() (which is a good idea regardless).